# In a batch file, how to find the occurrences of string in a textfile?

Tags: string, for-loop, batch-file

I'm having a text file and I want to run a batch file which reads the entire text file and tells me the no: of occurrences of a string "PASS":

Could you pl help how to do that - I'm not able to understand the usage of tokens in BAT file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the `findstr` command will help you: [Findstr Help](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true).
It doesn't print the number of occurences, but maybe you can do something with the results.

UPDATE:
The [Find command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find.mspx?mfr=true) has a `/c` option, which counts the number of lines containing that string.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Mulmoth is good and normally it should solve your problem.

But as you don't understand the tokens, I will try to explain it.

You can read the content of a file with the `FOR/F` command.
The `FOR/F` will read a file line by line, each empty line will be skip, also every line beginning with the EOL-character (default is `;`).

It uses per default `tokens=1 delims=<TAB><SPACE> EOL=;`.
In this case you got always one token till the line end or till the first `SPACE` or `TAB`.

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
  echo token1=%%a
)
```

if you want to read more tokens then you need to define it.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
  echo token1=%%a token2=%%b token3=%%c token4=%%d
)
```

Now the line will split into four tokens at the delimiter (SPACE or TAB) if there are less delims in a line then the tokens are empty.

If you don't want multiple tokens, or after a specific token the rest of the line you can use the `*`.
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4*" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
      echo token1=%%a token2=%%b token3=%%c token4=%%d
    )

Now, in token4 will be the fourth token and the rest of the line.

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
  echo token1=%%a token2=%%b token3=%%c token4=%%d
)
```

In this case only one token exists (`%%a`) the others (`%%b` `%%c` `%%d`) aren't valid tokens and the text `token2=%b token3=%c token4=%d` will be echoed.

You could also use the delim to reduce all to only one token.
    for /F "delims=" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
      echo complete line=%%a
    )

This works, as there can only one token, as there isn't any character left to split the line into more tokens.